# recursive function in python adding?

Tags: python, function, recursion, sum

So the question reads: Design a function that accepts an integer argument and return’s the sum of all integers from  1 up to the number passed as an argument. For example, if 50 is passed as an argument, the function will return the sum of 1,2,3,4…….50. Use recursion to calculate the sum.
im having lots of trouble as you can tell by my code

```
def main():
    numbers= int(input('Enter a number to add the sums: ')
    mysum = sum_num(numbers,1)


def sum_num(numbers,mysum):
    start=1
    end=numbers
    if start>end:
        return 0
    else:
        return my_sum
main()
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is the problem?  "im having lots of trouble..." is too vague for SO.

Comment: i cant get the code to work. also i dont know if im doing it right.

Comment: For a thing to be recursive, it has to... y'know. Call itself recursively. Might want to start there.

Comment: Well you don't even have recursion in your code...Maybe you can start by learning what a recursive function call is. Google examples for recursive fibonacci and recursive factorial functions. Those are the most basic, I think. You can also make a simple recursive exponentiation function for positive integer exponents.

Comment: This must be homework.  The sum of an arithmetic progression is the number of elements * the average of the first and last.

Comment: @nixvaldez Have you solved your problem? Did my answer worked for you? Be free to ask me anything to help you achieve what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sumup(n):
    # this one is your emergency break. you return 1 if n gets below
    # a certain threshold, otherwise you'll end up with an infinite
    # loop
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    # here is the recursion step, we return (n + "the sum to n+1")
    else:
        return n + sumup(n-1)

print(sumup(50))
```

Comment: how would i make it so the user can enter a integer? im guessing adding input on the print statement?

Comment: I only sketched the recursion you wanted. The `print` statement is only an example. You should read some basic tutorials on python (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), this is not the right place to talk about general programming.

Comment: BTW, useless `else` statement...

Comment: yea this one i like better simply because it looks similar to the book in class method. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Golfing a bit:

```
def sumup(n):
    return (n + sumup(n - 1) if n > 1 else n) if isinstance(n, int) else None
```

Comment: You made it longer and more complicated. Also golfing does not mean sticking to a specific implementation: `def f(n):
    return n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: @septi OP **needs** recursion. I've just simplified with pythonic features. My answer is even error-proof. Seems like you're just trying to convince OP to upvote and accept your answer no matter how wrong you're. Downvoting a valid answer... where's your fair play? StackOverflow is not about collecting rep. It's just about giving good answers.

Comment: 1. You did not simplify. 2. OP did not ask for code golf (not to mention that you did not "golf". Look up the definition of code golfing.) 3. You did not follow python's zen. 4. There is no need to check for `int` since the input is casted to `int` at the time of `int(input())` (and also, type checking is not pythonic at all). 5. You don't need returning `None`, since not returning anything is equal to returning `None`. 6. This one maybe the start of some golfing: `def f(n):
    return n + f(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1` 7. I'm not down voting any valid answers at all.

Comment: 1. Yes, I've simplified it with a Python feature added by Guido: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html 2. I've just used the term "golfing" for being short. You don't need to explain me what's code-golfing. KISS. 3. Why? It's ever relevant here? No. 4. You're assuming that based on OP example. If OP miss to cast the value to integer your solution simply won't work. And if type checking is not pythonic you wouldn't have `isinstance()` on Python. 5. Using that shortcut I **need** to return `None`, you should've known that. 6. I'm not golfing at all.

Comment: I shut down this stupid discussion from my side, this is my final answer. Type checking is almost never needed in python, deal with exceptions etc. follow the zen of python. And KISS doesn't meet your solution either and NO! you did not make it simpler. You made it complicated and less readable. Btw. the zen of python is always relevant and no I'll not answer any other of your comments. The coding style you showed here is ugly and if you don't agree with my opinion, read e.g. "Clean Code" from Robert C. Martin. However, think and do what you want and I don't care. Bye

Comment: I understand the fact that you have no argument. You don't need to tell me what I've to read and I don't care whatever you think at all. :)

Comment: Golfing: `f=lambda n:n and f(n-1)+n` if we can assume n is integer >= 0, otherwise `f=lambda n:n+(n>0and f(n-1))`.  Both are longer than the more natural `sum(range(n))`.